# On click event not firing on moving target

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am coding a JavaScript game, with a moving ball.
I want an alert message when the user manage to click on the moving ball.
It is working right now, but the event is not firing every times. It looks like the ball is moving too fast for the js engine to be able to notice that the ball was indeed clicked.
I am testing on Firefox 18, Windows 7 on a 5 years old cpu.

Here are some bits of my code :

```
myBall = document.getElementById("myBall");
function move(){
    myLeft += 20;
    myBall.style.left = myLeft + "px";
}    
myTimer = window.setInterval(move, 10);
...
myBall.addEventListener("click", function(){alert("win")});
```

Is there any way to set a click event listener on a small moving target, that will behave more accurately ? Would jQuery make any difference here?

Comment: Side note, animate using request animation frame and not setInterval.

Comment: Maybe the ball moves too fast for mouse button to go down and up? Have you tried adding event listener for "mousedown"?

Comment: html5 canvas + kinetic.js has quite a few cool options --> i have example ball on wwww.threeblokesfromchina.com

Comment: Note: The `click` event will not fire if the mouse coords for the `mousedown` event are not the same as the ones for the `mouseup` event. i.e. if the object moves between the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, `click` event wont fire. You should probably consider using just `mousedown`?

Comment: @lucas & techfoobar: that was it ! Great, thanks. Add it as an answer please !

Comment: @ianos : I guess canvas would be a nice option, but this game is for basic js learning purpose...

Comment: @lucas - You deserve the credit since you posted the right pointer first. You should post it as the answer.

Comment: @techfoobar Thanks. I hope I have included what's necessary to solve and understand the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All right, to solve the problem you're having, you'll need to add event listener for `mousedown` instead of `click`.

It is because `click` requires mouse button to go both down and up, and – as @techfoobar noted – it must be done at the same place on the target element (if coords of `mousedown` and `mouseup` are not equal, the `click` event won't be fired). The ball simply moves too fast to meet the aforementioned condition, hence the problem.